# Object Reference not set to an instance of an object? (Exception error ~ ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Currently i am using variables inside my view that have been declared within a model, and assigned values within the respective controller. I am using Model.variableName to reference these variables, however the following exception is thrown during debugging;

[image]

I am using the following namespaces within my view;

```
@using ProjectName.Models
@model Category
```

My class model;

```
public class Category
    {
        public string result { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller;

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ReadCategory()
        {
            var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");

            Category passCategory = new Category
            {
                result = "",
                delimiterChar = new[] { ',' },
                userData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile)
            };

            return View(passCategory);
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should be _@model Category_

Comment: Apologies, was suppose to have been written like so in the question.

Comment: are you sure the view is served by ReadCategory() ?  if yes, then something  BeginForm must happen to  set the value back to null. can you post that code as well?

Comment: Which code are you referring to? Sorry i am not entirely sure on what you mean?

Comment: I am not entirely sure that BeginForm is even necessary to begin with

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `return View(passCategory);`. Is it hit, and what is the value of `passCategory`?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't even get to that point, however after following the instructions given by Vassilis ive gotten it working. Gsharp hints towards this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your code to your index action result like this: (as I suspect your action result `ReadCategory` is not being utilized)

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Category.txt");

            Category passCategory = new Category
            {
                result = "",
                delimiterChar = new[] { ',' },
                userData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(dataFile)
            };

            return View(passCategory);
        }
```

Comment: I've just been graced by Vassilis.. thank you this works! <3